# Translation of Element in Html doesnt change on the Website (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, element

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I have the following problem:
I have a (Wordpress)Website and am using a nice theme there. My Website is german so I wanted to translate an element from english to german. So I went to the Theme Editor, found the Class and changed "view Profile" to "Profil anschauen". But it seems like that it doesn't update on the website. It's still the same there.

```
<li class="user-header">
            <?php echo get_avatar( um_user( 'ID' ), 84 ); ?>
            <p>
                <?php echo um_user( 'display_name' ); ?>
                <small class="mb-5">@<?php echo um_user( 'user_login' ); ?></small>
                <a href="<?php echo um_user_profile_url(); ?>" class="btn btn-profile">Profil anschauen</a>
            </p>
        </li>
```

I mean, there nothing else to change, so why does it not update?

Inspect Element on Website:
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rPdR.png)

Comment: Please check the theme file you edit via FTP/SFTP or cPanel File Manager. 
Don't modify the main theme files. Use child [theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) for theme customisation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the file via FTP and its also translated there. But again, on the Website itself its not. And the Child Theme doesnt have the option to modify this specific element

Comment: Which file did you edit via theme editor?